# parsing getopts

Tags: getopts

I want to escape the first string `SOMETEXT` in the `getopts` args. But I'm only able to do it in the first example.

How can I make it work on the second example?

```
while getopts p: opt
do
   case $opt in
   p) result=$OPTARG;;
   esac
done

echo "The result is  $result "
```

Example 1:

```
run_test.ksh -p3 SOMETEXT
The result is  3
```

Example 2:

```
run_test.ksh SOMETEXT -p3
./run_test.ksh: line 10: result: parameter not set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of using `getopts`. Parameters and their arguments must come before any other text.

If you know that the first word is `SOMETEXT` you could strip it from the argument list that `getopts` processes:

```
if [[ 'SOMETEXT' == "$1" ]]
then
    echo "Found SOMETEXT at the beginning of the line"
    shift
fi

while getopts p: opt
do
   case $opt in
   p) result=$OPTARG;;
   esac
done

echo "The result is  $result "
```

Comment: Hello Roiama ! Thank you for your comment. With shift I'm able to do it.